# Disable swipe removal notification in Android Oreo

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I am working on music application so i need to display notification on notification  bar. for that i am using custom notification. The following is the code for notification for Android Oreo

```
String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "001";
        RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.mynotification);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.exo_edit_mode_logo)
                    .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

            NotificationManagerCompat com = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            com.notify(001, notificationBuilder.build());

        }
```

This code is working fine, but when swipe the notification from notification bar it will be removed. But my requirement is not remove when swipe the notification.
I tried with **setAutoCancel(true)** and **setAutoCancel(false)**. But not working it will be removed. So how to stick the notification here.

Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `setOngoing(true)` to achieve this

Answer (score 3):

You have to add this `setOngoing(true)`

Try:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true);

Notification notification = builder.build();
```